In x86-64, how print all elements of an array?
section .data
    numbers db 240, 40, 80, 90, 30, 40

section .bss
    digit resw 1

%macro printNumber 1
    mov eax, %1
    
    %%printInt:
        mov rcx, digit      ;set rcx to digit memory address
        mov rbx, 10         ; moving a newline into rbx
        mov [rcx], rbx      ; setting digit to rbx
        inc rcx             ; increment rcx position by one byte

    %%storeLoop:
        xor rdx, rdx        ; zero out rdx
        mov rbx, 10         
        div rbx             ; rax / rbx (10)

                            ; rdx holds the remainder of the divison
        add dl, 48          ; add 48 to rdx to make in ascii character
                            
        mov [rcx], dl       ; get the character part of rdx
        inc rcx             ; increment digit position again

        cmp rax, 0
        jnz %%storeLoop       ; continue looping until rax is 0

    %%printLoop:
        push rcx

        ;perform sys write
        mov rax, 1 
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, rcx
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall

        pop rcx
        dec rcx
        cmp rcx, digit      ; first byte of digit (10)
        jge %%printLoop

%endmacro

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        mov esi,numbers
    
        
        ;movzx r8d, byte [esi]
        ;printNumber r8d           ; -> mov eax, r8d
        ;movzx r8d, byte[esi+1]
        ;printNumber r8d
        ;movzx r8d, byte[esi+2]
        ;printNumber r8d
     

I want to print all elements in array 'numbers', but when I launch code, result is not 240,40,80 but 240, 48, 52.
Why 48 and 52 is in result and how can I fix it?
I feel like the previous value is affecting it, but I really don't know how to fix it.
I want to print all elements in array..

You have a couple of obvious problems

you only allocate space for 2 characters with resw 1 in your digit array, but then store 3-4 characters there
you overwrite rsi in your macro to hold the argument to the syscall, but you use esi in your toplevel function to iterate over your numbers array

The first one is likely innocuous, as you don't have anything in .bss after digits (but if you did, you'd be clobbering that).  The second one means that after printing the first number, you'll get the wrong byte of memory to print next.  Since rsi is left pointing at the digits array, you'll end up printing characters from there as numbers -- thus the 48 you see (ascii 0) and 52 (ascii 4).
Obvious fix would be to push rsi at the start of the macro and pop rsi at the end of it to save and restore the value.
